# How to use a profile mapping in an attribute in Okta

Tags: saml, okta

I am trying to send through a group-based attribute from Okta as an attribute in an assertion.

I have configured a profile mapping for a field called "role" and have assigned the SAML 2 app to a group. On assignment, I defined role as "groupX".

However, the SAMLResponse / assertion doesn't contain "role" - how can I map the profile mapping field of "role" to a SAML attribute "role" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app was assigned to users via a group, and the profile field was set at the group level. The app was assigned to the group before the profile was updated, and didn't propagate to users.

By unassigning the app from the group and re-assigning it, the profile attribute was added to the assertion.